# Paramiko SFTP file renaming: OSError('Extended request not supported.')

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, fsspec

I can't find anything about this exception. I am trying to rename a remote file on a local (Windows) SFTP server with fsspec. Paramiko behind the scenes is doing a `posix_rename()`. What does the error mean?

```
fs.rename(old_file_path, new_file_path)
```

Paths look like `/folder/file.ext`.

I can rename files with other FTP clients on that same server.

Comment: You might also try with the related sshfs: https://github.com/fsspec/sshfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I just found that the SFTPClient is exposed through the SFTPFileSystem and I can call rename() on it directly, which worked!

```
fs.ftp.rename("testfile.txt", "x")
```

Comment: (feel free to accept your own answer, but also you might propose the PR to fsspec)

Comment: @mdurant I will do that, and thank you for your input!

Comment: https://github.com/fsspec/filesystem_spec/pull/884

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, fsspec `SFTPFileSystem.mv` calls Paramiko [`SFTPClient.posix_rename`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.posix_rename). That's imo a bad choice. The `SFTPClient.posix_rename` internally uses a proprietary OpenSSH `posix-rename@openssh.com` extension, which is naturally not supported by most other SFTP servers (such as yours).

I do not know what is the best solution/workaround. You can probably add your own "file system" implementation based on `SFTPFileSystem`, reimplementing `SFTPFileSystem.mv` to call standard Paramiko [`SFTPClient.rename`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.rename) (which uses standard SFTP rename request).